# Parse Json works partly - empty sub object

Tags: c#, arrays, json, .net-core, deserialization

I want to parse a json file. My first attempt with a simplified version was only partial successfull.

The simplifiend json structure looks like this

```
{
    "rowCount": 102,
    "data": [
        {"id": "56", "bezeichnung": "Main Center", "strasse": "foostreet"},
        {"id": "34", "bezeichnung": "Side Location", "strasse": "5th aveneue"}
    ]
}
```

For the outer json  `{ "rowCount":102, "data":[]}` i have a class `jsonEnvelope` which looks like this

```
public class JsonEnvelope
{
    public int RowCount { get; set; }
    public Location[] Data{ get; set; }
}
```

To parse the json inside the array data `"data":[]` i have `class location` which looks like this

```
public class Location
{
  public string id;
  public string bezeichnung;
  public string strasse;
}
```

My code to parse the json looks like this

```
string jsonString = GetJsonFromFile();
var jsonEnvelope = new JsonEnvelope();

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
jsonEnvelope = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonEnvelope>(jsonString, options);
foreach (Location h in jsonEnvelope.Data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} in {1}", h.bezeichnung, h.strasse));
}
Console.WriteLine("row count = " + jsonEnvelope.RowCount);
```

#### What is working?

The line `jsonEnvelope.RowCount` works. The number 102 is written to the console

The `foreach` is not working the values of `h.bezeichnung` and `h.strasse` are not written to the console

### Question

while writing my question i figured it out - i will self answer it briefly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that i used a field in class location instead of property.
Changing the class location to this solved the issue

```
public class Location
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Bezeichnung { get; set; }
    public string Strasse { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that with:

- .NET 5 or
- System.Text.Json package version 5 added to Core3.1 projects you can use `IncludeFields` option:

```
var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    IncludeFields = true,
};

var o = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Location>(json, serializeOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Hint "use fields only for variables that have private or protected accessibility. Data that your class exposes to client code should be provided through methods, properties, and indexers." [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields)